# .NET Core 3 with React - window.location.reload 401 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core

This is a .net core 3 react application where i'm trying to reload the current page if the user closes a modal.
Here is the modal close handler:

```
handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ show: false });
    window.location.reload(true); //I have also tried with default false
};
```

Here are the details from the browser:

```
General:    
Request URL: https://localhost:44378/Detail/ShowDetail
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 401 
Remote Address: [::1]:44378
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

ResponseHeaders:
date: Thu, 30 Jan 2020 23:34:31 GMT
server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
status: 401
www-authenticate: Bearer
x-powered-by: ASP.NET

Request Headers:
:authority: localhost:44378
:method: GET
:path: /Detail/ShowDetail
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.wTfz....
pragma: no-cache
referer: https://localhost:44378/Detail/ShowDetail
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-user: ?1
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36
```

Here's ConfigureServices in Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(
                IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtBearerScheme,
                options =>
                {                    
                    var onTokenValidated = options.Events.OnTokenValidated;

                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                    {
                        await onTokenValidated(context);
                    };
                });
```

Why am i able to navigate to this page without any issues but reloading causes a 401?
CORS related?  If so, how can that be resolved?

Comment: Well, 401 is an Unauthorized request. Therefore, my guess is that while you are navigating to the page, you are sending a request with some parameter (or header) which has been lost during the refresh and you are not handling a retrieve case on a reload. Can you tell me how you verify yourself against the server?

Comment: It's likely your React app is served at `https://localhost:44378` and the `/Detail/ShowDetail` is a route within the React app. So hitting the server with a request for `https://localhost:44378/Detail/ShowDetail` won't work because the server doesn't know about `/Detail/ShowDetail`, only `/` (React).

Comment: You are correct.  This being a SPA, i don't see any network traffic when i initially navigate to that page.  I suppose not attempting a reload and just clearing appropriate state properties might be the way to handle this

Comment: You can route all requests to `/` on the server side if you so desire. I would recommend `not attempting a reload and just clearing appropriate state properties` as you've said. (I'll submit this as an answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your React app is served at `https://localhost:4437` and the `/Detail/ShowDetail` is a route within the React app. So hitting the server with a request for `https://localhost:44378/Detail/ShowDetai`l won't work because the server doesn't know about `/Detail/ShowDetail`, only `/` (React).

You can route all requests to / on the server side if you so desire. I would recommend

> not attempting a reload and just clearing appropriate state properties

as you've said.